# Android WebView with notification on new message

Tags: java, php, android

I have messaging php based application where users login and send messages to each other.
I created an android app that is a WebView pointing to that website to give and in-app feeling to my users.

Now I'd like to add a notification feature to the app which will notify users every time they receive a message.

Is it possible to do so with a WebView based application ?

Thanks

Comment: It sure is, but you're going to have to provide a lot more detail. How to users receive messages on your other site?

Comment: Thanks rooftop, i think this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ answers my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send a notification from the php using Google Cloud Messaging every time there is a new message for that user.

Take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ as a basis to what I need to have done